# RuleDelayed with Simplify?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I have the Rule

```
yRule = y -> Function[{l,m,x},x^(l + 1) Exp[-((2 I m)/x)] Hypergeometric1F1[1 - l, -2 l, (2 I m)/x] ]
```

Is it possible to replace and simplify **just** the replaced part?

That is if I have some expression.

```
D[y[l,m,x],x] + y[l,m,x] /.yRule
```

I want it to produce the same as

```
Simplify[(D[y[l,m,x],x] /.yRule)] + Simplify[(y[l,m,x] /.yRule)]
```

Note that this isn't the same as applying `Simplify` to the whole system. My expressions are usually much longer than the ones above and I need to apply the `Simplify` exactly in the way demonstrated for numerical reasons.

I've tried playing around with `RuleDelayed`, but I can only simplify the parts with no derivatives.

Edit, I've just thought of a workaround.
We can upset the derivatives of y as some new function.

```
D[y[l,m,x],x] ^= ynew[l,m,x]
```

And then write a new rule for `ynew`

```
yRulenew = ynew -> Function[{l,m,x},Simplify[D[x^(l + 1) Exp[-((2 I m)/x)] Hypergeometric1F1[1 - l, -2 l, (2 I m)/x],x]] ]
```

but this isn't exactly ideal for hopefully obvious reasons.

Comment: `Simplify[# /. yRule] & /@ (D[y[l, m, x], x] + y[l, m, x])`

Comment: This works for the example I gave, but for `D[y[l,m,x],x]/y[l,m,x]` this would simplify the whole expression, not just the functions themselves.

Comment: @Nitaaa Then give a better example! We guess your actual application.